# send data from java client to nodejs server

Tags: java, javascript, json, node.js

So i send a normal string from a java client to the server and the server successfully recieves it.
The problem is that the recieved data is more than just the string which i originally sent.

i send the data in java with a DataOutputStream - > writeUTF("Welcome...");

See console output

## without using JSON.stringify()

### nodeJS client

```
connection --> 127.0.0.1
Data arrived type = string
Data = Welcome...
end
Disconnect --> 127.0.0.1
```

### java client

```
connection --> 127.0.0.1
Data arrived type = string
Data = 
Welcome...
end
Disconnect --> 127.0.0.1
```

## with JSON.stringify()

### nodeJS client

```
connection --> 127.0.0.1
Data arrived type = string
Data = "Welcome..."
end
Disconnect --> 127.0.0.1
```

### java client

```
connection --> 127.0.0.1
Data arrived type = string
Data = "\u0000\nWelcome..."
end
Disconnect --> 127.0.0.1
```

so i wonder how i can get rid of the stuff in front of my message when i recieve it from the java client? A normal replace() makes no sense because it varies.

Comment: Exactly how does it vary such that you can't use replace()?

Comment: "Welcome...dasdasdas" -->  "\u0000\u0013Welcome...dasdasdsa" or "W" --> "\u0000\u0001W"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be in the java side. Why are you using DataOutputStream? Try using the OutputStreamWriter class which is better suited for sending text.

Comment: Ok, first it didnt work because the data event on the server didnt fire but with  the use of out.flush() after the send function of the message on the client it worked. Thanks